# OpenSSL CBC Encrypt corruption of IV

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt "customer" information before writing that information to a file using the OpenSSL CBC-Mode for C.

When I try to encrypt the text it doesn't create an encrypted output it also appears to corrupt the given IV
It goes as follows

```
BANK: create-user bob 1234 1
PLAINTEXT: bob
IV: 9289437166649966
ENCRYPTION OF NAME OUTPUT:
0010 - <SPACES/NULS>        <-- encrypting name outputs nothing
PLAINTEXT: 1234
IV: ��=H�W��I��%%��� <-- IV becomes unusable afterwards
ENCRYPTION OF PIN OUTPUT:
0010 - <SPACES/NULS>        <-- Still no encryption output
```

The corrupted IV is always the same regardless of inputted IV

My code for generating the encryption is this:

```
unsigned char *cipher_name, *cipher_pin, IV[16], *IV_cpy*plaintext_n, *plaintext_p;
cipher_name = (unsigned char *) calloc(1000, sizeof(unsigned char));
cipher_pin = (unsigned char *) calloc(1000, sizeof(unsigned char));
plaintext_n = (unsigned char *) calloc(1000, sizeof(unsigned char));
plaintext_p = (unsigned char *) calloc(1000, sizeof(unsigned char));
int cipher_len;
.
.
.
rand_gen(IV);
IV_cpy = (unsigned char *)malloc(strlen((char *)IV));
memcpy(IV_cpy, IV, strlen((char *)(IV)));

strcpy((char *)plaintext_n,cmd[1]);
cipher_len = encrypt(plaintext_n, strlen((char *) plaintext_n), IV,cipher_name);
BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)cipher_name, cipher_len);
strcpy((char *)plaintext_p, cmd[2]);
memcpy(IV_cpy, IV, strlen((char *)(IV)));
cipher_len = encrypt(plaintext_p, strlen((char *) plaintext_p), IV, cipher_pin);
BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)cipher_pin, cipher_len);
```

I omitted the print statements to help readability.

The code that generates the IV is:

```
void rand_gen(unsigned char *ret_val) {
    int i, random;
    char rand_int[2];
    ret_val[0] = '\0';
    srand(time(0));
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            random = rand() % 10;
            if(random == 0) {
                    random = 1;
            }
            sprintf(rand_int, "%d", random);
            strcat((char *)ret_val, rand_int);
    }
```

}

The code for the encrypt function is

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char
*ciphertext, unsigned char *IV) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int ciphertext_len;
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, IV)) handleErrors();
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len)) handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors(); 
    ciphertext_len += len;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return ciphertext_len;
}
```

The key is available elsewhere which is why it's not in the function args

What is being output by encrypt:

```
0010 - <SPACES/NULS>
```

What encrypt is supposed to be outputting:

```
0000 - c7 2b 0a 46 7f 8e 2f e1-7d e6 a3 20 99 c2 7d 2b   .+.F../.}.. ..}+
```

Comment: Fyi, the IV fed to any of the IV-utilizing algorithms performed by EVP encipherment functions is intentionally updated inline. There'a a reason that buffer isn't addressed by `const unsigned char*`. And fwiw, there are many other ways to generate a random IV than what you're doing (which isn't very random at all).

Comment: Sorry, a little confused, but should I make a copy of the IV and use that for the second encryption?

Comment: Assuming you want to retain the original to kick of future decipherment, yes. Unless it is a known commodity you'll have to retain it somewhere. It isn't uncommon to emit it as the first frame of your cipher text, then continue with the remainder of the encryption, and the decryptor is aware of this strat.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice! I now have the same IV for each encryption, but I'm still not getting any output as in my encryption is still 0010 - <SPACES/NULS>, I'll be editing my above code to reflect the changes

Comment: Encrypted data won't necessarily be printable strings (in fact it's highly *unlikely*). Fire up a debugger and inspect the content of the memory behind `cipher_name` and `cipher_pin`.

Comment: The BIO_dump_fp part is what outputs the encryption as a readable string, I used the terminal version on the expected output and got an actual return. For instance inputting "bob" gave 0000 - c7 2b 0a 46 7f 8e 2f e1-7d e6 a3 20 99 c2 7d 2b   .+.F../.}.. ..}+

Comment: Derp. yeah, just saw that there. thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: It's not so much a problem of being readable, the ciphertext isn't being produced, I put an example of what it is supposed to be outputting and it's not giving anything like that

Comment: Fyi, he's not joking, nor hallucinating. I primed up his algorithm, and wrote one myself I'm *sure* is correct. upon executing either (the OPs or mine) on my macOS with 1.0.2o libcrypto, I get [something like this](https://pastebin.com/UdP5C90v), which I'm sure is what the OP is seeking. The *same* code ran on coliru [gives **this**](https://pastebin.com/WNEsiP3Z). Dare I ask, what OpenSSL libcrypto and/or platform is this on? Btw, in case anyone wonders, the linked output is the bin-dump of the random IV, the plaintext, and the cipher text. That spaces/null in the middle is just weird.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a VirtualBox VM, and I'm using "OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017"

Comment: Worth noting, the output with spaces/null is *missing* the intentional terminating byte of the plaintext buffer on the prior line (it's actually `char pt[] = "0123";` and i'm intentionally using the entire buffer, terminator and all). I just noticed that. how odd. If you can, look at the two side by side. Regardless, I *think* you're getting your cipher text, regardless of that bizarre output. I tested your function and it seems correct.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I wasn't suggesting you were joking. And I've only been at this for over a quarter-century now, including crypto since '93. The OP's *output* is what is confusing him, not encoding. He's purposely dumping to stdout using the very libcrypto API that is designed to do that: hex-dump to a file stream. it is the *inconsistencies* between two different builds of libcrypto (his is 1.1.0, mine is 1.0.2) that puzzles me. And if you read my prior two comments and still didn't take that away, then I doubt there is much I could add to make that outcome any different.

Comment: I tried to run what I had encrypted through the decrypt function to see if I was still getting the right data just outputting it poorly, but I got a "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:" error.

Comment: @RonocEroom Please set the IV to an explicit value for *each encrypt*. It is updated with the ciphertext of the previous encrypt - which you should not use anymore. You need the same IV value during encryption as used for the specific encrypt. Often the IV is stored before the ciphertext if it is random. Note that the IV should consist of random *bytes* with any value, not random *digits*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hmm, I see what you mean. I tried reading through the `BIO_dump_fp` but I can just say that it is an example on how to obscure simple hex output to the extreme. Are you expecting this an issue of the function or maybe of the output terminal? Sorry, I did not expect "dump" to mean: "pretty print bytes" (then again `-d` does mean that in the command line).

Comment: My current process is to encrypt the name, and pin using the same IV. Then put the two cipher texts into a file with the IV so they can be decrypted as needed later. I can make two seperate IVs but that seems unnecessary, but I may be wrong.  Also the openSSL guidelines say to use a 16-byte unsigned char which is what I'm using.

Comment: UPDATE: First thank you all so much for your help! Second, if I hard code the IV into the file that handles encryption it works fine, so somewhere between calling encrypt and actually doing the encryption, somethings going wrong. I think I can work past this, but once again thank you all so much for all the work you did! @WhozCraig

Comment: And @MaartenBodewes (sorry you can only tag one user per post)

Comment: **Your arguments are swapped.** You call encrypt with (plain_buf, plain_len, IV, cipher_buf) but encrypt's parameters are (plain_buf, plain_len, cipher_buf, IV) so it treats the (zeroed) cipherbuf as the IV and writes the ciphertext to the IV buffer. Since nothing is written to either cipher buffer they dump as all-zeros. Also in your edit you allocate IV_cpy and copy to it, but still use IV in the encrypt calls, so IV_cpy is effectively wasted.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That would certainly do it. I hope the OP is reading this still. And it also explains how I used the OP's encrypt code and still produce valid encryptions. I was actually calling it correctly.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes eh. no worries I think dave thompson hit it. This is the reason I prefer *not* wrapping the libcrypto APIs,  it's just too easy to flip something and it takes forever to catch it. In C++ i wrap all the contexts, keys, etc, with `std::unique_ptr` and specialized default-deleters, but other than that, it's EVP api all the way.

Comment: I'm smacking myself in the head thanks so much @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Ugh, should have seen that. OpenSSL does have "normal" parameter order. Key (static parameter), IV (dynamic parameter), plaintext (input). Most crypto libs use those parameters in that order. Of course Java and some other OO based APIs wrap the IV in an object, so this mistake is impossible. @WhozCraig Yeah, *generic* wrapper libs are horror shows. If you do create a method for encryption it better be application specific.